# Is there a workaround for animated SVGs (using CSS) on Edge and IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, css-animations, microsoft-edge, svg-animate

I have an SVG animation which is not working on Edge and obviously not on IE. I have done extensive research on the issue and am aware of using pixels for *stroke-dashoffset* and *stroke-dasharray* in order for it to work. I have done the same but it is not working. Now, as far as I know, Edge supports SVG animations at the moment; yet again, it is not working for me.

I was wondering if there are any workarounds, like a way to use a background image when the animation is not working? I searched a lot and was unable to find related topics. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes handwriting {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes handwriting {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes handwriting {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

.svg-text {
  width: 23rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: -2rem;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 7px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  z-index: 100;
}

.svg-text__animate {
  stroke-dasharray: 300px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 300px;
  animation: handwriting 0.8s linear forwards;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate {
  opacity: 1;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.8s;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.2s;
  animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.4s;
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.6s;
  animation-delay: 2.6s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--9 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.9s;
  animation-delay: 2.9s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--10 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.3s;
  animation-delay: 3.3s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--11 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--12 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.7s;
  animation-delay: 3.7s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--12 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--13 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.3s;
  animation-delay: 4.3s;
}

.svg-text--container .svg-text__animate--14 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.6s;
  animation-delay: 4.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner__1__content--l2 svg-text--container">
<svg class="svg-text" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 410 94.376">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="h"
                d="M310.345,298.912a.987.987,0,0,1,.457.774q0,.632-.809.632a1.542,1.542,0,0,1-.738-.211,6.2,6.2,0,0,0-2.426-.808q-2.145,0-4.781,4.289-9.282,15.117-13.746,39.586A60.811,60.811,0,0,1,301.415,325.6a4.584,4.584,0,0,1,2.32-1.407c.141,0,3.7,1.829,3.868,1.969a3.621,3.621,0,0,1,.914,2.813,11.783,11.783,0,0,1-.071,1.23,70.081,70.081,0,0,1-3.586,15.153q1.089-1.477,3.446-4.325a1.514,1.514,0,0,1,.949-.6q.387,0,.387.457a2.2,2.2,0,0,1-.457,1.195q-2.04,2.954-5.414,8.648-.282.563-1.372,2.954-.456,1.125-1.265,1.125a5.329,5.329,0,0,1-2.637-1.231q-.7-.492-.246-1.547,6.047-15.187,6.4-22.676.107-2.144-.6-2.144a4.88,4.88,0,0,0-1.934,1.195,40.078,40.078,0,0,0-6.644,7.735,65,65,0,0,0-8.051,14.941q-.774,2.181-1.442,2.18a5.593,5.593,0,0,1-2.355-1.442,2.49,2.49,0,0,1-.6-2.461q4.078-22.323,10.618-38.144,4.851-11.778,8.753-15.4a2.9,2.9,0,0,1,1.934-.914,4.6,4.6,0,0,1,2.5,1.125Q308.587,297.472,310.345,298.912Zm-6.61,25.277a4.527,4.527,0,0,1,3.868,1.969,3.621,3.621,0,0,1,.914,2.813"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-2" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="u"
                d="M339.208,327.986a72.646,72.646,0,0,0-7,20.391q.984-1.722,2.391-.395.175-.492.562-.492c.352,0,.527.223.527.668a1.166,1.166,0,0,1-.105.457,55.678,55.678,0,0,0-2.953,7.91q-.422,1.758-1.125,1.758a6.906,6.906,0,0,1-2.742-1.371q-1.09-.772-.739-2.742a86.79,86.79,0,0,1,3.551-13.324,125.245,125.245,0,0,1-11.391,16.277,2.631,2.631,0,0,1-2.214,1.16c-1.974-.283-4.746-1.933-4.746-3.34a5.425,5.425,0,0,1,.07-.843,56.461,56.461,0,0,1,3.656-16.7q-.6.563-1.793,1.653-.458.387-.7.211-.282-.212.1-.809a26.229,26.229,0,0,0,2.25-3.656,17.171,17.171,0,0,1,2.286-4.254,1.763,1.763,0,0,1,1.336-.774,6.131,6.131,0,0,1,2.777,1.125q.492.317.492.633l-.773,1.16q-1.76,2.673-3.727,9.422a45.669,45.669,0,0,0-2.18,11.918q0,1.512.633,1.512.563,0,1.828-1.3a83.886,83.886,0,0,0,7.84-10.9,93.906,93.906,0,0,0,5.485-9.211q1.581-3.586,2.566-4.219a2.1,2.1,0,0,1,1.125-.422,5.413,5.413,0,0,1,1.9.739q1.406.738,1.407,1.089c0,.071-.083.164-.246.282A1.082,1.082,0,0,0,339.208,327.986Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-3" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="m"
                d="M383.61,342.26q-2.286,3.41-6.82,12.023a2.861,2.861,0,0,1-.527.809,2.439,2.439,0,0,1-1.477-.176q-2.425-.738-2.426-1.406a3.182,3.182,0,0,1,.317-1.125,98.045,98.045,0,0,0,4.517-13.131,41.709,41.709,0,0,0,1.811-10.705q0-1.23-.879-1.231a2.381,2.381,0,0,0-1.406.668q-2.988,2.427-7.735,9.422a63.256,63.256,0,0,0-8.05,15.785,2.072,2.072,0,0,1-.422.95q-.211.105-1.02-.176a9.239,9.239,0,0,1-2.285-1.2,1.049,1.049,0,0,1-.527-.808q0-.071.527-1.371a60.039,60.039,0,0,0,4.6-22.324q0-1.089-.632-1.09a2.016,2.016,0,0,0-1.16.6q-3.764,3.165-8.368,10.9a71.915,71.915,0,0,0-6.609,13.851q-.562,1.653-1.16,1.653A7.321,7.321,0,0,1,341,352.6q-.562-.317-.563-.668c0-.258,2.825-6.75,4.043-11.742q2.074-8.544,1.793-12.411-.526.528-1.793,1.741t-1.9,1.845a1.257,1.257,0,0,1-.809.457q-.526,0-.527-.7a1.406,1.406,0,0,1,.387-.984,39.016,39.016,0,0,0,3.9-4.817q.7-.983,1.231-.984c.257,0,2.683,1.547,3.269,1.758a1.308,1.308,0,0,1,.738,1.3,2.742,2.742,0,0,1-.07.6A74.982,74.982,0,0,1,348,340.643q6.224-11.181,11.566-15.891a2.193,2.193,0,0,1,1.442-.668,19.064,19.064,0,0,1,4.148,2.074,3.038,3.038,0,0,1,.528,1.969,45.049,45.049,0,0,1-1.653,12.762q6.856-10.865,12.481-16.137a2.229,2.229,0,0,1,1.547-.7c.7,0,5.3,2.8,5.2,4.746a49.5,49.5,0,0,1-3.656,16.383,37.274,37.274,0,0,0,2.742-3.586,1.277,1.277,0,0,1,1.054-.738c.352,0,.528.188.528.562A1.649,1.649,0,0,1,383.61,342.26Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-4" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="a"
                d="M411.771,330.061a110.6,110.6,0,0,0-4.465,15.046,18.576,18.576,0,0,0,1.388-1.511,14.682,14.682,0,0,1,1.073-1.2,1.366,1.366,0,0,1,1.054-.632.466.466,0,0,1,.528.527,1.389,1.389,0,0,1-.282.738,28.5,28.5,0,0,0-4.394,9.879q-.317,1.406-.949,1.406a5.306,5.306,0,0,1-2.215-1.125,2.693,2.693,0,0,1-1.09-1.054,3.22,3.22,0,0,1,0-1.547,80.333,80.333,0,0,1,3.691-14.836,83.84,83.84,0,0,1-8.332,10.969,48.893,48.893,0,0,1-6.644,6.679,4.649,4.649,0,0,1-2.25,1.02,3.888,3.888,0,0,1-1.934-1.02,3.46,3.46,0,0,1-1.863-3.093,6.26,6.26,0,0,1,.07-.879q.633-5.2,4.571-12.112a48.7,48.7,0,0,1,9.035-11.654,4.469,4.469,0,0,1,2.953-1.512q1.266.072,4.816,3.34a.806.806,0,0,1,.317.6q0,.563-.739.562a1.326,1.326,0,0,1-.527-.105q-2.5-1.054-4.008.07-3.3,2.425-7.312,8.543-4.641,7.032-5.59,12.656a3.167,3.167,0,0,0-.035.457q0,.879.7.879a4.52,4.52,0,0,0,2.847-1.652,93.5,93.5,0,0,0,8.438-9.633,48.781,48.781,0,0,0,5.906-9.07q.95-2.25,1.231-3.164.456-1.582.984-1.582a6.82,6.82,0,0,1,2.461,1.441,1.926,1.926,0,0,1,.879,1.09A3.482,3.482,0,0,1,411.771,330.061Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-5" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="n"
                d="M441.97,340.959q-2.111,3.2-5.485,9.281-.633,1.582-1.23,3.164-.494,1.089-1.3,1.09a5.305,5.305,0,0,1-1.863-.527q-1.371-.562-1.371-1.125a3.338,3.338,0,0,1,.457-1.09,61.207,61.207,0,0,0,4.078-11.566q1.932-7.278,1.652-11.11-.07-1.547-.7-1.547-.458,0-1.371.879-8.859,8.649-15.328,23.133-.81,1.792-1.9,1.793a7.022,7.022,0,0,1-2.566-.879q-.7-.316-.738-.6a4.677,4.677,0,0,1,.386-.984,85.558,85.558,0,0,0,4.043-11.32,59.364,59.364,0,0,0,2.426-11.567q.071-1.264-.07-1.265-.036,0-.984.949t-2.637,2.461a.973.973,0,0,1-.7.316c-.329,0-.492-.128-.492-.386a.969.969,0,0,1,.351-.633q1.511-1.933,3.973-4.817a1.482,1.482,0,0,1,1.09-.6c.562,0,4.265,2.66,4.148,3.832q-.387,3.867-3.973,13.957a63.318,63.318,0,0,1,6.856-10.143q4.5-5.607,6.68-6.627a4.536,4.536,0,0,1,1.546-.492c.305,0,4.383,2.579,4.36,4.148a41.953,41.953,0,0,1-1.2,7.911q-.948,4.5-1.757,7,1.019-1.3,2.6-3.375a.765.765,0,0,1,.563-.352q.526,0,.527.668A1.324,1.324,0,0,1,441.97,340.959Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-6" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="l"
                d="M486.548,298.912a.967.967,0,0,1,.457.738q0,.669-.809.668a1.542,1.542,0,0,1-.738-.211,6.2,6.2,0,0,0-2.426-.808q-2.214,0-4.851,4.289-9.564,15.575-13.606,40.254-.1.668-.351,1.793.808-.844,2.39-2.742.915-1.089,1.336-1.09.915,0,.141,1.09a27.023,27.023,0,0,0-4.465,10.089q-.387,1.3-.984,1.3a1.438,1.438,0,0,1-.739-.316q-1.793-1.2-2.039-1.406a2.473,2.473,0,0,1-.7-1.829,6.6,6.6,0,0,1,.176-1.371q4.078-22.393,10.512-38.144,4.851-11.883,8.683-15.4a2.978,2.978,0,0,1,2.11-.949,4.835,4.835,0,0,1,2.461,1.195Q484.823,297.471,486.548,298.912Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-7" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="a-2" data-name="a"
                d="M496.673,330.061a110.6,110.6,0,0,0-4.465,15.046A18.552,18.552,0,0,0,493.6,343.6a14.556,14.556,0,0,1,1.072-1.2,1.367,1.367,0,0,1,1.055-.632.466.466,0,0,1,.527.527,1.394,1.394,0,0,1-.281.738,28.5,28.5,0,0,0-4.4,9.879q-.317,1.406-.949,1.406a5.311,5.311,0,0,1-2.215-1.125,2.7,2.7,0,0,1-1.09-1.054,3.246,3.246,0,0,1,0-1.547,80.326,80.326,0,0,1,3.692-14.836,83.929,83.929,0,0,1-8.332,10.969,48.94,48.94,0,0,1-6.645,6.679,4.646,4.646,0,0,1-2.25,1.02,3.883,3.883,0,0,1-1.933-1.02,3.459,3.459,0,0,1-1.864-3.093,6.273,6.273,0,0,1,.071-.879q.632-5.2,4.57-12.112a48.721,48.721,0,0,1,9.035-11.654,4.471,4.471,0,0,1,2.953-1.512q1.266.072,4.817,3.34a.8.8,0,0,1,.316.6q0,.563-.738.562a1.331,1.331,0,0,1-.528-.105q-2.5-1.054-4.007.07-3.306,2.425-7.313,8.543-4.641,7.032-5.59,12.656a3.317,3.317,0,0,0-.035.457q0,.879.7.879a4.52,4.52,0,0,0,2.848-1.652,93.5,93.5,0,0,0,8.437-9.633,48.8,48.8,0,0,0,5.907-9.07q.948-2.25,1.23-3.164.456-1.582.984-1.582a6.82,6.82,0,0,1,2.461,1.441,1.926,1.926,0,0,1,.879,1.09A3.466,3.466,0,0,1,496.673,330.061Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-8" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="n-2" data-name="n"
                d="M526.872,340.959q-2.109,3.2-5.484,9.281-.633,1.582-1.231,3.164-.492,1.089-1.3,1.09a5.311,5.311,0,0,1-1.863-.527q-1.371-.562-1.371-1.125a3.338,3.338,0,0,1,.457-1.09,61.137,61.137,0,0,0,4.078-11.566q1.933-7.278,1.653-11.11-.072-1.547-.7-1.547-.456,0-1.371.879-8.859,8.649-15.328,23.133-.808,1.792-1.9,1.793a7.025,7.025,0,0,1-2.567-.879q-.7-.316-.738-.6a4.712,4.712,0,0,1,.387-.984,85.7,85.7,0,0,0,4.043-11.32,59.439,59.439,0,0,0,2.426-11.567q.069-1.264-.071-1.265-.034,0-.984.949t-2.637,2.461a.973.973,0,0,1-.7.316c-.329,0-.492-.128-.492-.386a.969.969,0,0,1,.351-.633q1.512-1.933,3.973-4.817a1.483,1.483,0,0,1,1.09-.6c.562,0,4.266,2.66,4.148,3.832q-.387,3.867-3.972,13.957a63.371,63.371,0,0,1,6.855-10.143q4.5-5.607,6.68-6.627a4.533,4.533,0,0,1,1.547-.492c.3,0,4.382,2.579,4.359,4.148a42.015,42.015,0,0,1-1.195,7.911q-.95,4.5-1.758,7,1.02-1.3,2.6-3.375a.762.762,0,0,1,.562-.352c.352,0,.527.223.527.668A1.324,1.324,0,0,1,526.872,340.959Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-9" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="g"
                d="M555.138,328.619q-10.794,56-28.055,55.969-6.222,0-13.465-6.856a1.815,1.815,0,0,1-.668-1.3q0-1.022.949-1.02a1.457,1.457,0,0,1,.95.387q5.73,4.885,10.265,4.887,14.484,0,24.153-42.54-5.873,10.092-10.231,14.45a4.814,4.814,0,0,1-3.129,1.793,5.663,5.663,0,0,1-3.129-1.407,5.365,5.365,0,0,1-3.2-5.414q.212-4.605,3.551-11.425a35.329,35.329,0,0,1,6.82-10.02,5.634,5.634,0,0,1,3.621-1.9,4.6,4.6,0,0,1,2.637,1.054q.212.177,2.813,2.5a1.262,1.262,0,0,1,.527.914q0,.633-.844.633a2.842,2.842,0,0,1-1.195-.316,4.388,4.388,0,0,0-2.074-.563,3.937,3.937,0,0,0-2.672,1.055,27.76,27.76,0,0,0-5.379,7.313,31.314,31.314,0,0,0-3.762,10.125,15.3,15.3,0,0,0-.176,2.144q0,2.6,1.407,2.6a3.09,3.09,0,0,0,2-.95,42.8,42.8,0,0,0,8.3-10.371,51.635,51.635,0,0,0,5.45-11.5,11.638,11.638,0,0,0,.6-3.551q0-1.335.633-1.335a6.252,6.252,0,0,1,2.6,1.476Q555.594,326.334,555.138,328.619Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-10" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="u-2" data-name="u"
                d="M585.2,327.97a72.646,72.646,0,0,0-7,20.391q.984-1.722,2.391-4.395.175-.492.562-.492.528,0,.528.668a1.151,1.151,0,0,1-.106.457,55.678,55.678,0,0,0-2.953,7.91q-.421,1.758-1.125,1.758a6.913,6.913,0,0,1-2.742-1.371q-1.09-.773-.738-2.742a86.682,86.682,0,0,1,3.55-13.324,125.356,125.356,0,0,1-11.39,16.277,2.63,2.63,0,0,1-2.215,1.16c-1.974-.283-4.746-1.933-4.746-3.34a5.55,5.55,0,0,1,.07-.843,56.492,56.492,0,0,1,3.656-16.7q-.6.563-1.793,1.653-.456.387-.7.211-.282-.211.106-.809a26.439,26.439,0,0,0,2.25-3.656,17.14,17.14,0,0,1,2.285-4.254,1.763,1.763,0,0,1,1.336-.773,6.127,6.127,0,0,1,2.777,1.125q.492.315.492.632l-.773,1.161q-1.758,2.672-3.727,9.421a45.7,45.7,0,0,0-2.179,11.918q0,1.512.633,1.512.561,0,1.828-1.3a84,84,0,0,0,7.839-10.9,93.906,93.906,0,0,0,5.485-9.211q1.582-3.587,2.566-4.219a2.107,2.107,0,0,1,1.125-.422,5.423,5.423,0,0,1,1.9.739q1.405.738,1.406,1.089c0,.071-.083.164-.246.282A1.091,1.091,0,0,0,585.2,327.97Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-11" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="a-3" data-name="a"
                d="M611.458,330.061a110.6,110.6,0,0,0-4.465,15.046,18.552,18.552,0,0,0,1.389-1.511,14.556,14.556,0,0,1,1.072-1.2,1.367,1.367,0,0,1,1.055-.632.466.466,0,0,1,.527.527,1.394,1.394,0,0,1-.281.738,28.5,28.5,0,0,0-4.395,9.879q-.317,1.406-.949,1.406a5.311,5.311,0,0,1-2.215-1.125,2.7,2.7,0,0,1-1.09-1.054,3.246,3.246,0,0,1,0-1.547,80.326,80.326,0,0,1,3.692-14.836,83.929,83.929,0,0,1-8.332,10.969,48.94,48.94,0,0,1-6.645,6.679,4.646,4.646,0,0,1-2.25,1.02,3.883,3.883,0,0,1-1.933-1.02,3.461,3.461,0,0,1-1.864-3.093,6.273,6.273,0,0,1,.071-.879q.633-5.2,4.57-12.112a48.747,48.747,0,0,1,9.035-11.654,4.471,4.471,0,0,1,2.953-1.512q1.266.072,4.817,3.34a.8.8,0,0,1,.316.6q0,.563-.738.562a1.322,1.322,0,0,1-.527-.105q-2.5-1.054-4.008.07-3.3,2.425-7.313,8.543-4.641,7.032-5.59,12.656a3.317,3.317,0,0,0-.035.457q0,.879.7.879a4.52,4.52,0,0,0,2.848-1.652,93.5,93.5,0,0,0,8.437-9.633,48.747,48.747,0,0,0,5.907-9.07q.949-2.25,1.23-3.164.456-1.582.985-1.582a6.837,6.837,0,0,1,2.461,1.441,1.923,1.923,0,0,1,.878,1.09A3.466,3.466,0,0,1,611.458,330.061Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-12" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="g-2" data-name="g"
                d="M639.688,328.619q-10.792,56-28.054,55.969-6.224,0-13.465-6.856a1.815,1.815,0,0,1-.668-1.3q0-1.022.949-1.02a1.453,1.453,0,0,1,.949.387q5.731,4.885,10.266,4.887,14.484,0,24.152-42.54-5.871,10.092-10.23,14.45a4.814,4.814,0,0,1-3.129,1.793,5.66,5.66,0,0,1-3.129-1.407,5.365,5.365,0,0,1-3.2-5.414q.212-4.605,3.551-11.425a35.288,35.288,0,0,1,6.82-10.02,5.634,5.634,0,0,1,3.621-1.9,4.606,4.606,0,0,1,2.637,1.054q.21.177,2.812,2.5a1.26,1.26,0,0,1,.528.914q0,.633-.844.633a2.835,2.835,0,0,1-1.2-.316,4.392,4.392,0,0,0-2.075-.563,3.941,3.941,0,0,0-2.672,1.055,27.782,27.782,0,0,0-5.378,7.313,31.314,31.314,0,0,0-3.762,10.125A15.3,15.3,0,0,0,618,349.08q0,2.6,1.406,2.6a3.09,3.09,0,0,0,2-.95,42.819,42.819,0,0,0,8.3-10.371,51.627,51.627,0,0,0,5.449-11.5,11.61,11.61,0,0,0,.6-3.551q0-1.335.633-1.335a6.251,6.251,0,0,1,2.6,1.476Q640.146,326.334,639.688,328.619Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-13" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="e"
                d="M661.239,343.455c-5.7,7.29-9.713,11.147-12.023,10.934-4.216-.389-6.82-4.207-6.82-5.59a4.907,4.907,0,0,1,.07-.809,58.459,58.459,0,0,1,2.566-10.652q-1.3-.668-1.3-1.266,0-.492.739-.492a2.486,2.486,0,0,1,1.16.316q3.129-7.031,5.625-9.984,1.617-1.968,2.918-1.969a11.294,11.294,0,0,1,2.953,1.02q-.175-1.055.6-1.231c.023,0,3.164.176,3.164.528a4.41,4.41,0,0,1-.106.6,4.407,4.407,0,0,0-.105.914q0,1.266.035,3.129t.035,2.5q0,4.36-2.391,6.083a8.174,8.174,0,0,1-4.921,1.582,24.451,24.451,0,0,1-4.782-.774,19.5,19.5,0,0,0-1.336,4.254,27.565,27.565,0,0,0-.914,7.1q.036,1.827,1.16,1.828a3.818,3.818,0,0,0,1.09-.211q4.078-1.442,11.356-8.789a1.318,1.318,0,0,1,.914-.457q.668,0,.668.632A1.283,1.283,0,0,1,661.239,343.455Zm-4.113-15.539q0-1.371-.6-1.371a2.231,2.231,0,0,0-1.125.562q-3.446,2.778-6.047,9.739.7.105,2.461.211a5.481,5.481,0,0,0,4.254-1.3,5.122,5.122,0,0,0,1.16-3.481Q657.126,334.069,657.126,327.916Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="clip-path-14" transform="translate(-277.94 -292.292)">
            <path id="s"
                d="M675.056,345.494c-.056,4.506-7.137,8.695-8.192,8.789a9.977,9.977,0,0,1-2.179-.105q-2.074-.317-5.1-.774a1.169,1.169,0,0,1-1.02-1.019q.141-.949,1.969-1.125,2.5-.176,7.383-.879a3.619,3.619,0,0,0,2.6-2.074,4.319,4.319,0,0,0,.457-2.075q0-2.214-2.215-7.8-2.18-5.449-2.039-7.278.28-4.393,8.121-6.117.773-.176.773.563,0,.422-.562.668-3.8,1.653-3.8,4.078a10.268,10.268,0,0,0,.351,2.373q.353,1.424,2.11,6.838A20.474,20.474,0,0,1,675.056,345.494Zm5.625-20.18a24.454,24.454,0,0,1-.844,5.063,3.382,3.382,0,0,1-.7,1.547,4.249,4.249,0,0,1-1.2.527,6.928,6.928,0,0,1-1.617.492q-.527,0-.527-.7a4.926,4.926,0,0,1,.141-1.019,15.251,15.251,0,0,0,.65-4.834q-.194-1.353.791-1.7a7.129,7.129,0,0,1,2.215-.879Q680.68,323.8,680.681,325.314Z"
                style="fill: none" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g id="h-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--1" id="h-path"
                points="34.06 8.708 27.06 4.708 22.06 10.708 15.06 24.708 11.06 37.708 7.06 57.708 16.06 43.708 24.06 34.708 27.06 33.708 29.06 34.708 22.06 60.708 27.06 54.708 32.06 47.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="u-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-2)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--2" id="u-path"
                points="36.06 43.708 39.06 39.708 42.06 34.708 44.06 35.708 41.06 42.708 40.06 46.708 38.06 55.708 38.06 58.708 38.06 59.708 40.06 60.708 43.06 57.708 53.06 43.708 58.06 34.708 60.06 35.708 57.06 42.708 55.06 48.708 52.06 60.708 53.06 60.708 58.06 50.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="m-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-3)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--3" id="m-path"
                points="62.06 40.708 69.06 32.708 72.06 34.708 69.06 48.708 65.06 60.708 73.06 45.708 79.06 36.708 83.06 33.708 86.06 34.708 86.06 41.708 84.06 49.708 81.06 60.708 88.06 47.708 94.06 38.708 100.06 33.708 103.06 35.708 103.06 41.708 100.06 53.708 97.06 61.708 107.06 46.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="a-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-4)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--4" id="a-path"
                points="129.06 36.708 124.06 32.708 118.06 38.708 111.06 49.708 108.06 58.708 111.06 60.708 116.06 56.708 127.06 43.708 131.06 35.708 133.06 36.708 128.06 52.708 127.06 60.708 130.06 53.708 134.06 48.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="n-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-5)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--5" id="n-path"
                points="138.06 38.708 143.06 32.708 147.06 35.708 142.06 51.708 138.06 59.708 140.06 60.708 145.06 49.708 151.06 40.708 157.06 34.708 159.06 33.708 162.06 35.708 159.06 51.708 155.06 60.708 156.06 61.708 160.06 52.708 165.06 46.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="l-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-6)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate  svg-text__animate--6" id="l-path"
                points="210.06 8.708 203.06 4.708 193.06 20.708 183.06 58.708 184.06 60.708 187.06 54.708 191.06 47.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="a-grp-2" data-name="a-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-7)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--7" id="a-path-2" data-name="a-path"
                points="213.963 36.708 208.963 32.708 202.963 38.708 195.963 49.708 192.963 58.708 195.963 60.708 200.963 56.708 211.963 43.708 215.963 35.708 217.963 36.708 212.963 52.708 211.963 60.708 214.963 53.708 218.963 48.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="n-grp-2" data-name="n-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-8)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--8" id="n-path-2" data-name="n-path"
                points="222.963 38.708 227.963 32.708 231.963 35.708 226.963 51.708 222.963 59.708 224.963 60.708 229.963 49.708 235.963 40.708 241.963 34.708 243.963 33.708 246.963 35.708 243.963 51.708 239.963 60.708 240.963 61.708 244.963 52.708 249.963 46.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="g-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-9)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--9" id="g-path"
                points="272.06 36.708 266.06 33.708 260.06 38.708 255.06 48.708 253.06 57.708 258.06 61.708 263.06 55.708 271.06 43.708 274.06 36.708 274.06 33.708 276.06 34.708 271.06 55.708 266.06 70.708 260.06 82.708 253.06 88.708 249.06 90.708 244.06 89.708 233.06 82.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="u-grp-2" data-name="u-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-10)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--10" id="u-path-2" data-name="u-path"
                points="282.049 43.692 285.049 39.692 288.049 34.692 290.049 35.692 287.049 42.692 286.049 46.692 284.049 55.692 284.049 58.692 284.049 59.692 286.049 60.692 289.049 57.692 299.049 43.692 304.049 34.692 306.049 35.692 303.049 42.692 301.049 48.692 298.049 60.692 299.049 60.692 304.049 50.692" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="a-grp-3" data-name="a-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-11)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--11" id="a-path-3" data-name="a-path"
                points="328.748 36.708 323.748 32.708 317.748 38.708 310.748 49.708 307.748 58.708 310.748 60.708 315.748 56.708 326.748 43.708 330.748 35.708 332.748 36.708 327.748 52.708 326.748 60.708 329.748 53.708 333.748 48.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="g-grp-2" data-name="g-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-12)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--12" id="g-path-2" data-name="g-path"
                points="356.611 36.708 350.611 33.708 344.611 38.708 339.611 48.708 337.611 57.708 342.611 61.708 347.611 55.708 355.611 43.708 358.611 36.708 358.611 33.708 360.611 34.708 355.611 55.708 350.611 70.708 344.611 82.708 337.611 88.708 333.611 90.708 328.611 89.708 317.611 82.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="e-grp">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-13)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--13" id="e-path"
                points="364.06 42.708 372.06 45.708 377.06 45.708 381.06 43.708 382.06 39.708 382.06 32.708 380.06 32.708 380.06 33.708 376.06 32.708 372.06 38.708 368.06 47.708 366.06 56.708 367.06 58.708 370.06 60.708 373.06 60.708 385.06 48.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="s-path">
        <g style="clip-path: url(#clip-path-14)">
            <polyline class="svg-text__animate svg-text__animate--14" id="s-path-2" data-name="s-path"
                points="400.06 41.708 401.06 32.708 396.06 33.708 391.06 36.708 395.06 51.708 395.06 54.708 391.06 59.708 387.06 60.708 379.06 59.708" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems due to IE doesn't support [SVG animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate).

I think the easiest workaround to this is using a gif in IE. I make a gif of the animation and make loop count of it to once using [this tool](https://ezgif.com/loop-count). The outcome gif is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrK6Y.gif). We can use IE specific css rules to show the gif and hide other parts in IE:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   /* IE10+ CSS */
    #gif-img{
        display:block;
    }
    .banner__1__content--l2 svg-text--container {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```
<div id="gif-img">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrK6Y.gif" />
</div>
<div class="banner__1__content--l2 svg-text--container">
    ...
</div>
```

In Edge, I found that the animation will work if we make the value of `stroke-width` large enough. But the outcome is still a little different from that in Chrome and [the New Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) (You could try to update to the latest Edge Chromium official build):

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
    /* Edge 16+ CSS */
    .svg-text {
        stroke-width: 700px;
    }
}
```